# Exportar datos de bd a un archivo Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente código para descargar datos de sql en un excel, el problema es que me descarga el excel vacio, solo con los encabezados, ya lo depuré y la consulta si me trae datos.
Me he guiado con este [tutorial](http://abctutorial.com/Post/25/how-to-export-database-data-in-excel-file-using-aspnet-mvc) pero nose que he hecho mal.
He declarado esto **int rowStart = 42;** porque mi query me devuelve 42 filas

```html
public void ExportToExcel()
{
  ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
  ExcelWorksheet ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");

  ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Titulo";
  ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "Id";
  ws.Cells["B2"].Value = "Nombre";
  ws.Cells["C2"].Value = "Edad";
           
  var data = bd.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("Select ...").ToList();

   int rowStart = 42;
   foreach (var item in data)
   {
   ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Id;
   ws.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Nombre;
   ws.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Edad;
   rowStart++;
   }

   ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();
   Response.Clear();
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment: filename=" + "ExcelReport.xlsx");
   Response.BinaryWrite(excel.GetAsByteArray());
   Response.End();
}
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado colocar otros valores al rowStart como 30-20-10-5-2-1?

Comment: @fredyfx hola no lo habia pensado, ya lo probe y no se escribe nada :T

Comment: Si colocas un breakpoint, ¿tienes datos antes del ciclo for?

Comment: @fredyfx asi es si obtengo los datos

Comment: ¿y te has fijado que el excel el orden de las columnas sea el esperado? Una vez me pasó que el excel había juntado las celdas a tal punto que a simple vista, estaba vacío, cuando miré de nuevo vi que los números estaban saltados, es decir, la altura de cada celda la habían puesto en cero.

Comment: @fredyfx el nombre de las columnas me aparece correcto

Comment: podrias poner un breakpoint dentro del foerach y ver si item.Id, item.Nombre tienen valor? Fijate que el rowstart arranca en 42, va a insertar en A42 B42 el primero y seguira subiendo

Comment: ¿Podrías subir el excel a github, por favor?

Comment: @fredyfx hola lo subi a mega https://mega.nz/#!c4NUXKob!D8xmPmOOFFZ9r69CtEXh3rlXHSF5ndhksGPovz91jvw estoy teniendo problemas para subirlo a github nose porque

Comment: tengo bloquedo mega y otros sitios, por eso te decía github... un commit a github?

Comment: Mira lo que encontré en tu mismo archivo líneas más abajo https://imgur.com/nOzvyPd

Comment: @fredyfx jaja si ya me vi la respuesta de abajo, que verguenza, gracias

Comment: haha, relax hermano, todos somos aprendices constantes :) lo que me sorprende es que no haya funcionado con cambiarle los valores del rowStart, en teoría debió haberte mostrado "más arriba" los valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta iniciar la variable **rowStart en 3** si la inicias en 42 tus datos se iniciaran a mostrar apartir de la linea 42 revisa tus archivos más abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambiando la variable para que inicie en 3 se mira asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el codigo que use, es un metodo de api en .net core:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("testExcel")]
        public IActionResult testExcel()
        {

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(stream);
            ExcelWorksheet ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");


            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Titulo";
            ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "Id";
            ws.Cells["B2"].Value = "Nombre";
            ws.Cells["C2"].Value = "Edad";

            List<Test> data = new List<Test>()
            {
                new Test() { Edad = 20, Id = 1, Nombre = "Test1"},
                new Test() { Edad = 20, Id = 1, Nombre = "Test2"}
            };

            int rowStart = 3;
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Id;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Nombre;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Edad;
                rowStart++;
            }

            ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();

            excel.Save();
            stream.Position = 0;

            return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "nombreExcel.xlsx");

        }
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: jaja que verguenza si era por eso. Gracias

Comment: nada de vergüenza hermano, todos estamos en aprendizaje constante, así que  relax :)